# restriction on the number of nodes in Corda current version

Tags: blockchain, corda

It would be great if someone can share below.

Do we have restriction on the number of nodes or parties in Corda. As per technical research papers, Hyperledger do have a restriction of 16 nodes. Beyond 16 nodes, PBFT doesn’t work and hence it is hard to reach consensus on the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Corda doesn't have a restriction on the number of parties to a transaction, but I suspect you mean the limit on the [notary](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-notaries.html) cluster size, for reaching [uniqueness consensus](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-consensus.html#uniqueness-consensus).

In this case it depends on the consensus algorithm used. The current BFT notary implementation uses BFT-Smart, which is based on PBFT, and will likely not scale beyond 16 nodes either – although there's no strict limit enforced yet. This limitation is mainly dictated by the type of the algorithm, and will be similar on all platforms.

However, in Corda there is an expectation that there will be multiple notary clusters in a network, operated by selected small groups of semi-trusted parties, and parties can choose which notary to use based on who they trust. So the limitation of PBFT does not actually impose limitations on the platform.

Comment: Thanks for the revert. However, it is unclear why PBFT doesn't impose limitations on platform.  As I understand, because of PBFT only consensus cannot be reached beyond 16 nodes.

Comment: Yes, but there is no notion of _global_ consensus in Corda, as compared to traditional blockchain platforms. 16 or fewer nodes is sufficient for the purpose of a notary service (PBFT cluster). I'd suggest having a quick look at the [key concepts docs](https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts.html)

Comment: @AndriusDagys- does these multiple notaries share data among themselves?

Comment: They don't, but it's possible to repoint a state from one notary to another.